# How would I improve this 7 line Linq Query that acts as a Specification?

Tags: linq-to-entities, where-clause

BigQuery at the top gets a set of Products and nested related tables.  Then, I apply filtering in a poor attempt at a specification pattern.  This is the filter code.  There are three tables in the query, and I want to filter the top query by the value nested in the bottom query.  Like I said, this currently produces the results we want.

However, the .Contains() produces a SQL WHERE EXISTS() clause for each.  We really only need one, but I don't know how to get the inner ID to compare with the outer ID.

```
from p in bigQuery                            // Root table
where ( from pp in p.LPP                      // Level 1 nested table
        where (from pv in pp.LPV              // Level 2 nested table 
               where pv.colorid == intValue   // Our filter value
               select p.id).Contains(p.id)    // Where exists
        select p.id).Contains(p.id)           // Where exists
select p;
```

Any thoughts?  This produces a 900 line SQL statement as-is, and we only have one filter so far.

Comment: Why are you selecting p.id in the innermost query?

Comment: I thought I needed something that could compare to the outer set of IDs.

Comment: Shouldn't that be pv.id though? Else AFAIC see, the result will always be true.

Comment: Actually, the same goes for query around it too. It might be correct, but looks like a mistake to me.Verify that the filter actually does filter as intended.

Comment: It definitely does filter correctly.  I am not getting 450 records that are in the original set, I am getting 130.  I verified that every record id matches what is displayed in the form against the SQL code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from p in bigQuery
where p.LPP.SelectMany(pv => pv.LVP).Any(x => x.colorid == intValue)
select p;
```

From what I can see, the above should be equivalent. Please try it and inspect the SQL generated, if working. Any case, it should not be far off.

Comment: TYVM It improved the select statement by 100 lines