# How to use EXISTS in where condition of LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have gone through couple of similar questions but couldn't find what I wanted.

I need to find tags which has a ID in Answers table, since there could be multiple answers records containing the tag ID I need to take care of the duplicates. This is the reason why I cant perform simple join.

I thought about using an EXISTS but couldn't figure out the way to do it yet.

This is the working SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT TagName
FROM Tags tag
JOIN Answers ans ON ans.StID = tag.Id  
WHERE tag.SchId = 472
 AND ans.isValid = 1
```

This is what I tried in LINQ with no success

```
(from tag in Tags
 where tag.Id.Any(from ans in Answers
                  where ans.StID == tag.Id
                  && tag.SchId == 472
                  && ans.isValid == true
                  select ans.ID)
select tag.TagName
```

It would be helpful if someone can suggest a way to correctly implement this query in LINQ.

Comment: This post suggests `Any` is how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074013/how-to-do-a-sql-where-exists-in-linq-to-entities.  When you used `Any` it didn't do that?  How are you checking?

Comment: `where tag.SchId == 472 && Answers.Any(ans => ans.StID == tag.Id
 && ans.isValid)`

Comment: @PeterRitchie No it didnt work, It said type int? (which is a type of tag id) doesnt contain a definition for Any

Comment: @IvanStoev trying your way

Comment: @Y.Solanki ah, okay, I missed that part.  Any/EXISTS is a row-level check so you can't use it on a particular field.  I think what ivanstoev showed, or something similar, should do what you want.

Comment: @IvanStoev That works, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll generally want to accomplish this by using the [`Enumerable.Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method to pass in a function that will check if any items in your collection meet a given criteria :

```
var x = Tags.Where(t => t.SchId == 472 && Answers.Any(a => a.StId == tag.Id && a.isValid))
            .Select(t => t.TagName)
            .Distinct();
```

This should give you a list of distinct tags that have a `SchId` of 472 and have at least one valid answer.

Comment: Surely `a.StId == tag.Id` should be `a.StId == t.Id`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Distinct method which will get rid of your duplicates. Try the code below.

```
(from tag in Tags
where tag.Id.Any(from ans in Answers
                  where ans.StID == tag.Id
                  && tag.SchId == 472
                  && ans.isValid == true
                  select ans.ID).Distinct(ans => ans.ID)
select tag.TagName
```